# In source tree, which is "mine" and which is "theirs" in merge diff?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm merging two branches. I assume I'm on *HEAD* branch right now. When I only want to pick one branche's version of the file. The one I want to pick depends on the contents, not on the branch.

For example on the image below I want to pick the second line:

[image: In source]

But from which line does the second line come? I do not really understand the output of the program here.

Comment: `<<<HEAD...===` means this `...` part is from the checked-out branch's head, which is `ours`. `===...>>>origin/kuna_pridani_veci_pro_ZS` means this `...` part is from the branch `origin/kuna_pridani_veci_pro_ZS`, which is `theirs`.

Comment: So the *theirs* line is above `>>>origin/kuna_pridani_veci_pro_ZS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The branch names are right there next to the conflict markers. The one you used with your last checkout is "ours", the one you mentioned in the `git merge` command is theirs.

In fact, I cannot do better than to quote `git help merge`:

```
   By default, Git uses the same style as the one used by the "merge" program from the RCS suite to present such a
   conflicted hunk, like this:

       Here are lines that are either unchanged from the common
       ancestor, or cleanly resolved because only one side changed.
       <<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
       Conflict resolution is hard;
       let´s go shopping.
       =======
       Git makes conflict resolution easy.
       >>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
       And here is another line that is cleanly resolved or unmodified.

   The area where a pair of conflicting changes happened is marked with markers <<<<<<<, =======, and >>>>>>>. The part
   before the ======= is typically your side, and the part afterwards is typically their side.
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a little test with Sourcetree (4.1.0, 24Mar2021) that clarifies at least this use case

```
branch mineA, text "a"
branch mineB, text "b"
current branch: mineB
merge mineA into mineB
resolve conflict using 'mine'
text: "b"
```